# If $X \sim Bin(n,p)$, using $E(X(X-1)) = g''(1) = n(n-1)p^2$ show that Var$(X) = npg$.

Tags: probability, generating-functions

If $X \sim Bin(n,p)$ using $E(X(X-1)) = g''(1) = n(n-1)p^2$ show that Var$(X) = npg$.

I understand that g is the generating function $g_{x}(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_{k}t^{k}$, and I know that the mean, E(X) = $g''(1) = n(n-1)p^2$. But does E(X(X-1) represent? And how does it prove that the Var(X) = npq?

Comment: I didn't work this out, but by linearity, $E(X(X-1)) = E(X^2) - E(X)$, so you can easily relate this to $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$ knowing $E(X) = n$.

Comment: Isn't the E(X) = np?

Comment: You will need to know or derive the fact  that the probability generating function of the Binomial is $(q+pt)^n$, where $q=1-p$. By the way, $g'(1)=np$. It is $g''(1)$ which is equal to $n(n-1)p^2$.

Comment: @larrysummersstatistics, yes of course, I just typed that too quickly.

Comment: The mean is $\Bbb E(X)=g'(1)=np$ and not $g''(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observing that
$$\begin{align}
g'(1) &=\Bbb E(X)\\
g''(1)&= \Bbb E(X(X − 1))
\end{align}
$$
so you have
$$
\begin{align}
g''(1)+g'(1)-[g'(1)]^2 &=\Bbb E(X(X − 1))+\Bbb E(X)-[\Bbb E(X)]^2\\
&= \Bbb E(X^2) -\Bbb E(X)+\Bbb E(X)-[\Bbb E(X)]^2\\
&= \Bbb E(X^2) -[\Bbb E(X)]^2\\
n(n-1)p^2+np-(np)^2&=\mathrm{Var}(X)=npq
\end{align}
$$

Comment: So, $g''(1) = n(n-1)p^2$, but how do you get from $n(n-1)p^2$ to $E(X(X-1))$?

Comment: It's in your hypotesis! You kwnow that $\Bbb{E}(X(X-1))=g''(1)=n(n-1)p^2$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(X)&=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2\\
&= \mathbb{E}[X(X-1)]+\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2 & \text{linearity}\\
&= n(n-1)p^2 + np - (np)^2 & \mathbb{E}[X]=np\\
&= np[(n-1)p + 1 - np]\\
&= np(1-p)\\
&= npq
\end{align*}

Comment: How do I get from $
\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2 \text{ to } 
 \mathbb{E}[X(X-1)]+\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2$

Comment: @larrysummersstatistics $$\mathbb{E}[X(X-1)]=\mathbb{E}[X^2-X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]$$

Answer (score 0):

Note for pgf the general differentiation rule for m th derivative( repeated derivative m times),  when s = 1  is given by

g^m (1) = E( X(X - 1) ......... ( X - m + 1))

and so it follows g^2(1) = n(n - 1 )p^2 for the Binomial R.V. X